# pythondns - two identical strings return not equal

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code and in the last if statement I just want to compare the two strings.

```
import dns.resolver

domain = "google.co.uk"

spf_wrong ='"v=spf1 -all"'

test_spf = dns.resolver.resolve(domain , 'TXT')
try:
    for dns_data in test_spf:
        if 'spf1' in str(dns_data):
            dns_correct = dns_data
except:
    print("SPF record not found")
    pass

if dns_data == spf_wrong:
    print("same")
else:
    print("not same")
    print(dns_correct)
    print(spf_wrong)
```

To me, the output shows the exact same text. There is nothing different about it but I get the output:

```
not same
"v=spf1 -all"
"v=spf1 -all"
```

Finding another thread I then modified the if statement to the following:

```
if dns_data == spf_wrong:
    print("same")
else:
    print("not same")
    print(repr(dns_correct))
    print(repr(spf_wrong))
```

And now I get the following output:

```
not same
<DNS IN TXT rdata: "v=spf1 -all">
'"v=spf1 -all"'
```

So my question is, how do I act on this? Python thinks these strings are different and I think using the repr() function shows they are different, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but `str(dns_data)==spf_wrong` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dns_correct is not a string it's a `<class 'dns.rdtypes.ANY.TXT.TXT'>`

A string will probably never be `==` to this class.

When you call `print()` you're implicity calling the `__str__()` function on rdtypes.ANY.TEXT.TEXT which is why it looks like they are the same when you print them.

You can think of print as doing this:

`print(str(dns_correct))`

Here's the python3 repl session I used. It should clarify further.

```py
>>> import dns.resolver
>>>
>>> domain = "google.co.uk"
>>>
>>> spf_wrong ='"v=spf1 -all"'
>>>
>>> test_spf = dns.resolver.resolve(domain , 'TXT')
>>> try:
...     for dns_data in test_spf:
...             if 'spf1' in str(dns_data):
...                     dns_correct = dns_data
... except:
...     print("except")
...
>>> dns_correct
<DNS IN TXT rdata: "v=spf1 -all">
>>> print(dns_correct)
"v=spf1 -all"
>>> type(dns_correct)
<class 'dns.rdtypes.ANY.TXT.TXT'>
>>> str(dns_correct) == spf_wrong
True
>>> dns_correct == spf_wrong
False
```

If you look @ the source we find `__str__` function calls another func called `to_text` which produces the output you see when you print

```py
# https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.rdata-pysrc.html#Rdata.__str__
186 -    def __str__(self): 
187          return self.to_text()
```

```py
# https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.rdtypes.txtbase-pysrc.html#TXTBase.to_text
49 -    def to_text(self, origin=None, relativize=True, **kw): 
50          txt = '' 
51          prefix = '' 
52          for s in self.strings: 
53              txt += '{}"{}"'.format(prefix, dns.rdata._escapify(s)) 
54              prefix = ' ' 
55          return txt
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much for this, really detailed and helpful.
I understand it now and now I can use:  


`if str(dns_data) == str(spf_wrong):
    print("same")
else:
    pass`
Thanks again!